# How do I neutralize 1.2 % muriatic acid (134.4 liters) residue with 99 % caustic soda flakes?

Tags: acid-base

I cleaned my commercial water purification system with muriatic acid but I overdid it. Now there is excess muriatic acid residue. I used 6 liters of  29 % muriatic acid and further reduced with 33.6 gallons (134.4 liters) water as solvent at 1.2 % concentration of muriatic  hcl.I believe the mole for the solution is 3.29 moles, is that right?

I have  99 % caustic soda flakes that I can use to neutralize muriatic acid residue. How do I go about it? How do I mix caustic soda at the right amount to neutralize the muriatic acid residue?

I'm not a chemist or a student so  I would really, really appreciate your help guys. I'm on the verge of losing my small business if I don't fix this.

Comment: Better using backing soda and you just add it until gas evolution ceases. Don't forget standard safety behavior.

Comment: I can't. I have to mix this in the tank and run through the whole machine provided I allow the caustic soda to settle down a bit after a few minutes. Besides that baking soda leaves a residue. I tried it once, didn't like it.

Comment: Hi rich, I'm inclined to believe that the community closed this for the wrong reason (it does look like a homework question, funnily enough, but I'm sure that this is an actual problem you are facing).  Your edit has put it into the reopen queue so that people can vote to reopen it.  I'm not a chemist of any import, but I would say that the amount of flakes that you put in would depend on the amount of the *residue*, not necessarily the amount of solution that you originally put in.

Comment: Thank you Jonsca for your reply. I measured the water. It measured 5.10 ph. Usually chlorinated water measures around 6.30 ph. And I could really taste the acidity of the water though it has lessened somewhat after a few days. The acidity even sticks to my gums when I taste it. Isn't there a way to calculate  how much caustic soda I would need to adjust the ph judging from the measurement I took ?

Comment: Of course there is a way. Problem is I cannot trust the dara you provide

Comment: For a rough calculation assume density is about 1. The amount of hcl is the 1% of about 134 kg. So 1340 g of HCl. This divided by the molecular way gives about 37 moles. Then multiplying by the soda mw gives you about 1480 g of caustic soda. Use goggles.

Comment: Alchimista, theres no need to be rude to me.                                                     The ph meter is the only instrument I have to measure the water.

Comment: Rich I wasn't rude!  I wanted to say that I take the conc with care as otherwise you could have answered yourself. However at about 1 percent whatever you refer to mass/mass or msss/volume there is w much change and I decided to give you the receipt. You will end up at more or less the original pH of your water.  Br careful handling caustic soda.

Comment: Ok, I 'm a bit stressed right now. I'm a small businessman, not a chemist so you got to a bit patient with me.

Comment: The 134.4 liters is the water I mixed with 6 liters of  29% Hcl. Bringing down the concentration to 1.2 % Hcl.  Isn't 1480 grams ( or more than a kilo) a bit too much ?

Comment: I refer to title!. I will look for what you have done step by step but later. ...

Comment: Let us make it simple.  The current molarity of your solution is 10 to the power -pH so it is about 10 to minus 5.2. You have this amount of moles HCl for each liter. 0.000052 times Volume of water times 40 gives you the amount of caustic soda in grams.

Comment: :))) actually 10 to minus 5.2 equals to 0.0000063. The rest is unchanged :)))

Comment: Eh.. you lost me. How many grams ? I studied history back in college, not math because math confuses me.Alchimista I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is that 3.3 grams  of caustic soda needed ?

Comment: I think it would be a bad idea to calculate a certain amount of caustic soda and then add this total calculated amount. Your assumptions for the calculation could easily be wrong. If replacing the water in the system is not an option, I would rather add small amounts of diluted NaOH and measure the pH after each step. Be sure that it has mixed with the water in the system properly to avoid false measurements.

Comment: 0.0000063 × 40 × actual V in liters = grams of NaOH.

Comment: @Aventurin gave a good advice too. That brings all back to my first comments ;)

Comment: Alchimista, I just want to clarify. The answer to your calculation is .00338688. Does that mean I move the decimal point twice? That's .33 grams of caustic soda needed ?